# How I can read user input with asterisk.net library?

Tags: c#, asterisk, voip

I'm using asterisk.net in C#.  After prompting an user to input a digit, how I can have the digit on the C# side?

I have tried this event, but it didn't fire in this case

```
private void Manager_NewState(object sender, Asterisk.NET.Manager.Event.NewStateEvent e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depend of how you pormpted input.

If you used Read application, it will set variable. So you need read channel variable